# what TimRough garden says about intuition behind quick sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

When I was watching this [video](https://youtu.be/uLeIMwMHX5U?list=PLXFMmlk03Dt7Q0xr1PIAriY5623cKiH7V&t=513) on probability review by TimRough Garden from Stanford, he says that, the problem explaining that the probability that the pivot is chosen such that the split is 25-75, is 50%. And he adds saying "This gives intuition why quick sort is quick"

But that is guaranteed only when the quick sort pivot choosing guarantees that it is chosen 25-75 range right ?

How can one guarantee that probability of pivot choosing to be 50 % ?

If that is not guaranteed then quick sort can be slowest with 
O( n<sup>2</sup>  ) runtime complexity right  ?

Comment: Yes.  Quicksort has a worst-time complexity of O(n^2).  However, under most circumstances it is O(n log n).

Comment: how to make that circumstance 50 % probable ?

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam - The probability is based on the assumption that the data is random or near random. Using [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) prevents O(n^2) time complexity, but this reduces performance. Another option is to track recursion depth and switch to heap sort if the depth exceeds some pre-determined limit, such as [intro sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) .